# About redis bitmap structure memory storage problem

Tags: redis, bitmap

for example

```
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 2 1
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 3 1
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 5 1
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 10 1
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 11 1
> SETBIT bitmapsarestrings 14 1
> GET bitmapsarestrings
"42"
```

Binary storage should not like this: **0010 0110 0001 1100** ?

stored in this way, why value is 42?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `SETBIT` operations will make the value as a binary string, whose length is 2 bytes or 16 bits. After the settings, the value will be `0b 00110100 00110010` in binary format.

The first byte (`0b 00110100`) is `52`, which is the ascii code of '4', and the second byte (`0b 00110010`) is `50`, which is the ascii code of '2'. So when you get the value of the string, it returns "42".

Answer (score 1):

What @for_stack said, or just refer to the lines immediately above that example (https://redis.io/commands/setbit):

> Bitmaps are not an actual data type, but a set of bit-oriented operations defined on the String type (for more information refer to the Bitmaps section of the Data Types Introduction page). This means that bitmaps can be used with string commands, and most importantly with SET and GET.
>
> Because Redis' strings are binary-safe, a bitmap is trivially encoded as a bytes stream. The first byte of the string corresponds to offsets 0..7 of the bitmap, the second byte to the 8..15 range, and so forth.